# Create DDL scripts for other db systems

Tags: sql, ddl, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I know that its possible to generate DDL scripts with JetBrains DataGrip, but is there any way to generate a DDL script for other db systems. In my case i must migrate my PostgresSql db to a MsSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with DataGrip.

The only workaround you can use is to copy the table to other data source of another vendor via pressing `F5` on a table. It will show you the dialog where DDL preview is available. This DDL is the DDL for your "new" data source with appropriate type conversions.

[image]